# Why Can't I Update an Object in Array using a "helper" Variable?

Tags: arrays, swift, updating

I'm asking this out of curiosity to understand Swift.

I'm trying to update objects in an array situated in another class.

I have two cases (the other one works, and other one doesn't)

1. Working solution:

```
    Data.tripModels[0].title = "lol"
```

2. Not working:

```
    var trip = Data.tripModels[0]
    trip.title = "lol"
```

To help you understand:

```
    Data = the other class
    tripModels = the array in Data class, holding the objects
    title = a property of tripModel in tripModels array
```

Why is the 2. not working? :(

Comment: Are the items in the tripModels array instances of a `struct`?

Comment: @vacawama yes :)

Comment: Then @vadian's answer explains the issue. `struct`s are value types, so you're updating a *copy*.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you for your help! I'm new to struct s ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2. does not work because due to value semantics (the type of *tripmodel* is a struct) the line

```
var trip = Data.tripModels[0]
```

assigns a **copy** of the item in the array to `trip` and

```
trip.title = "lol"
```

updates the copy but not the item in the array.

Please read [Structures and Enumerations are Value Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html#ID88) in the Swift Language Guide

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response. Now that you said it it makes sense to me also... Would it work if I would leave the [0] out of the variable? Or would it just save a copy of the whole array instead of a reference?

Comment: It creates also a copy of the array. But you can reassign the changed item: `var trip = Data.tripModels[0]; trip.title = "lol"; Data.tripModels[0] = trip`